# why I am losing syntax highlighting when vim is invoked within a script?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

If I initiate vim from command line prompt, everything works as expected, but when it is initiated from a script, then syntax color highlighting is lost. The script can be as simple as the following,

```
 #!/bin/bash
 vi NR_NK.f
```

Please help me find out why this is the case, and how to possibly fix it.

Comment: that's vi not vim right?

Comment: Is `vi` an alias for `vim`? Aliases are not normally exported and will not be seen by scripts. Therefore, your script may be running the program `vi` in your PATH, which is often a minimal version of Vim without support for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thank you guys, you solved my problem. Please reply my question so that I can choose your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mass pointed out, your script is running `vi`, not `vim`. That may be because you have `vi` as an alias for `vim` and are used to typing `vi` rather than `vim` on the command line. Aliases are not expanded by bash when the shell is not interactive, as when it is processing your script. Therefore, your script may be running the program `vi` in your PATH, which is often a minimal version of Vim without support for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Also if `vim` is invoked as `vi` it will set `compatible` and a bunch of other other options that disable "modern" features like syntax highlighting.

Comment: I just tried that, creating a symlink from `vim` to `vi` and running that vi. Syntax coloring still worked. I think reverting to `vi` behavior depends on more that just the program name, but I can't find that in the help at the moment.